# Spring boot dosen't invoke queries form data.sql file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a project like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRfwe.png) and have some query in data.sql file:

```
insert into user_role(role, description) VALUES ("ROLE_USER", "default role for user");
```

And Spring boot doesn't execute this query. Why ? Everything is working fine, tables are created correctly in database, but Spring Boot doesn't put that query to the database, I must invoke that query manually. The query have no errors when I manually execute it.

Comment: what is error stack in console.

Comment: Maybe post the rest of the data.sql file.

Comment: have you wrote "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update " line in your application.properties file

Comment: No error in console. That's all of data.sql, I have: spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop, when I add update to spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop-update I have error: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory

Comment: can you update your question with the content of your `application.properties`? `create-drop-update` does not exist, the possible values are: `none, validate, update, create, and create-drop` I assume your pom.xml and application.properties are correct and you did execute `mvn clean install`

Comment: Yes, everything in pom.xml and application.properties is fine, and a executed mvn clean install. When I do query from /register or /login page everything working fine, only that data.sql dosen't automaticly invoke